# Change JHipster home page depending on the authority

Tags: java, angularjs, jhipster

I saw some answers here but I couldn't solve my problem.

I have a new authority, called `ROLE_X`, and after the login, I would like to redirect the users with this authority to a new module, for example `dashboard`.

If the user has the default authority like `ROLE_USER`, he should be redirected to the `home` module as usual.

Can someone help me? I'm using Angular 1.x. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `home.component.ts` :

```
    registerAuthenticationSuccess() {
     this.eventManager.subscribe('authenticationSuccess', (message) => {
        this.principal.identity().then((account) => {
            if (account.authorities.indexOf("ROLE_X") >=0)
            {
                this.router.navigate(['PATHTOYOURPAGE']);
            }
            else
            {
                this.account = account;
            }
        }); 
     });
   }
```

Instead, you can do the same in login.component.ts, as you wish.

Comment: I think I should mentioned it, but I'm using angular 1 and I couldn't find the `home.component.ts`, only `_home.component.ts` in `generator-jhipster` package. Is this the same? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: I just edited my question to mention the angular version that I'm using.

Comment: Oh sorry, you should also edit the tag, Angular tag is for Angular2, for Angular 1.x you should use Angularjs instead
I think you can implement the same logic, but do it in src/main/webapp/app/home/home.controller.js
In the getAccount() function

Comment: I just edited the tag. And yes, your solution worked! Can you please edit your answer or answer again, so I can mark it as resolved? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm doing more tests here, its happening a weird behavior. Its working, but before going to `dashboard`, it always hit the `home` and then goes to `dashboard`... is there a way to avoid it?!

Comment: Hi, Im trying to use your solution to make users navigate to different home pages based on their authority. However, I get the following error,                       
 TS2551: Property 'router' does not exist on type 'HomeComponent'. Did you mean 'route'?. Im new to angular, so I must be doing something wrong.